# Does Pidgin support video-chatting with Google Plus users?

Tags: pidgin, google-talk, video-chat, google-plus

Does Pidgin support video chatting with Google Plus users? Just today a friend was trying to video chat with me on pidgin. He said he was *calling* me, but I didn't get the usual Pidgin prompt to answer his call. When I right click to view his info rather than showing me his gmail address it shows me,

> Info for 3i7l4jba[..redacted_random_characters..]@public.talk.google.com

Further it shows his resource is,

> Resource: android_talk34ba4c8966bb

I believe he is logged into Google Plus with his phone. Is this an issue with Pidgin?

This contact has *not* added me to his contact with list GMail -- this is a question specific to video chatting with Pidgin/Google Talk <-> Google Plus (or maybe even more specifically, Google Plus on the Android).